# change element in state array does not trigger UI change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `ListView` component in which I need to change the background color of each row independently according to an onPress event.

```
<View style = {[styles.checkBox, {backgroundColor: this.state.button[rowID]? '#62C6C6':'transparent'}]}/>
```

Because I don't know how many rows will be rendered, but at most there'll be 4, so I declared an array state `button` as `[false, false, false, false]` and change element value according to the row. For example when I press the first row, with `rowID` is 0, I will set the state of `button` to be `[true, false, false, false]`. In this method, the state for `button`  is changed, but the UI does not rerender the background color . 
I think the logic here is correct(ish?), is there any way I can get the expected result or there's a smarter way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion will be to create your own component to render inside each row and only changing the background of that component when clicked. Which then means you don't need to keep an array of the state the state will be in each component itself.

This will be your component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backgroundColor:'transparent'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
            <Text>This is my Component</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  changeColor(){
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor:'#62C6C6'
    });
  }
}
```

Then in you renderRow you can call your component:

```
renderRow(rowData){
 return(
  <View>
    <MyComponent/>
  </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: i was thinking the same way, so I'll just accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

For ListView dataSource needs to be  reset again to trigger changes.

Make dataSource as state, as shown in the sample 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: I'm not really changing data source in this case,  just change the row background color independently on each row.

Comment: Yes. Make the button states as part of array and use dataSource as state. clone from the new array and set the dataSource.

Comment: u mean add the button states to my original dataSource of the ListView? but that will re-render the whole ListView right?

Comment: Not necessarily. That will depend on the rowHasChanged function. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html